C++ program (VS 2018 or higher) to read a input data from weka arff file and generate OneR output
I am getting this error `Expression: Vector subscript out of range1 every time I try to run:
Debug Assertion failed!
Program: <path to x64 Debug EXE>
File: <VC 14 include directory>\vector
Line: 1894
Expression: vector subscript out of range

I am not understanding where I need to correct
OneR rule is a set of rules that all based on value of a SINGLE attribute.  This should also print the error rate of the oneR rule (set) on the training set
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Define structures to hold ARFF data
struct Instance {
vector<string> attributes;
string classLabel;
};

struct ARFFData {
vector<string> attributeNames;
vector<vector<string>> attributeValues;
vector<string> classLabels;
vector<Instance> instances;
};

// Function to parse ARFF file
...
}

// Function to calculate error rate of OneR rule
double calculateErrorRate(const ARFFData& data, const string& attribute, const string& classLabel) {
// Implement error rate calculation logic here
return 0.0; // Placeholder, replace with actual calculation
}

// Function to find the best OneR rule
pair<string, double> findOneRRule(const ARFFData& data) {
// Implement OneR algorithm logic here
string bestAttribute;
double minErrorRate = 1.0; // Initialize with maximum error rate

// Iterate over attributes and find the one with the minimum error rate
for (const auto& attribute : data.attributeNames) {
// Calculate error rate for this attribute
double errorRate = calculateErrorRate(data, attribute, data.classLabels[0]);

// Update best attribute if error rate is lower
if (errorRate < minErrorRate) {
m....
}

return make_pair(bestAttribute, minErrorRate);
}

int main() {
// Parse input ARFF file
ARFFData data = parseARFF("input.arff");

// Find the best OneR rule
pair<string, double> oneRRule = findOneRRule(data);

// Print the OneR output
cout << "OneR Rule: If " << oneRRule.first << " then " << data.classLabels[0] << endl;
cout << "Error Rate: " << oneRRule.second << endl;

return 0;
}



subscript out of range means you are accessing an invalid index in a container.  You need to use your debugger to find which line of your code causes the crash and then you need to step through the execution around that code to see why it doesn't do what you expect.

What a reason of spamming in the irrelevant tags?

Visual Studio has a great debugger, you should learn how to use it. Using the debugger will tell you which vector has the problem, what the subscript is, and what the size of the vector is. Once you know those things you can start thinking about what caused the vector subscript error and how you can fix it

The main function starts with ARFFData data = parseARFF("input.arff");. If that fails, all indexing into data will be out of range. Perhaps some error checking would be helpful?

std::vector::operator[] does not check range. You should verify that the vector has content using the empty or size method before trying to read the first element.

The message-box is better posted as text. Otherwise, the code sample and explanation was sufficient to identify that it was a lock of range-checking.
